# Extract word/sentence probabilities from lm_1b trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, lstm, language-model

I have successfully downloaded the 1B word language model trained using a CNN-LSTM (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/lm_1b), and I would like to be able to input sentences or partial sentences to get the probability of each subsequent word in the sentence.

For example, if I have a sentence like, "An animal that says ", I'd like to know the probability of the next word being "woof" vs. "meow".

I understand that running the following produces the LSTM embeddings:

```
bazel-bin/lm_1b/lm_1b_eval --mode dump_lstm_emb \
                           --pbtxt data/graph-2016-09-10.pbtxt \
                           --vocab_file data/vocab-2016-09-10.txt \
                           --ckpt 'data/ckpt-*' \
                           --sentence "An animal that says woof" \                             
                           --save_dir output
```

That will produce files `lstm_emb_step_*.npy` where each file is the LSTM embedding for each word in the sentence. How can I transform these into probabilities over the trained model to be able to compare `P(woof|An animal that says)` vs. `P(meow|An animal that says)`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing and this is what I came up with, adapted from some of their demo code. I'm not entirely sure this is correct but it seems to produce reasonable values.

```
def get_probability_of_next_word(sess, t, vocab, prefix_words, query):
  """
  Return the probability of the given word based on the sequence of prefix 
  words. 

  :param sess: Tensorflow session object
  :param t: Tensorflow ??? object
  :param vocab: Vocabulary model, maps id <-> string, stores max word chard id length
  :param list prefix_words: List of words that appear before this one. 
  :param str query: The query word
  """
  targets = np.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, NUM_TIMESTEPS], np.int32)
  weights = np.ones([BATCH_SIZE, NUM_TIMESTEPS], np.float32)

  if not prefix_words or prefix_words[0] != "<S>":
    prefix_words.insert(0, "<S>")

  prefix = [vocab.word_to_id(w) for w in prefix_words]
  prefix_char_ids = [vocab.word_to_char_ids(w) for w in prefix_words]

  inputs = np.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, NUM_TIMESTEPS], np.int32)
  char_ids_inputs = np.zeros(
    [BATCH_SIZE, NUM_TIMESTEPS, vocab.max_word_length], np.int32)
  inputs[0, 0] = prefix[0]
  char_ids_inputs[0, 0, :] = prefix_char_ids[0]
  softmax = sess.run(t['softmax_out'],
                     feed_dict={t['char_inputs_in']: char_ids_inputs,
                                t['inputs_in']: inputs,
                                t['targets_in']: targets,
                                t['target_weights_in']: weights})

  return softmax[0, vocab.word_to_id(query)]
```

Example usage

```
vocab = CharsVocabulary(vocab_path, MAX_WORD_LEN)
sess, t = LoadModel(model_path, ckptdir + "/ckpt-*")
result = get_probability_of_next_word(sess, t, vocab, ["Hello", "my", "friend"], "for")
```

gives a result of `8.811023e-05`. Note that `CharsVocabulary` and `LoadModel` are very slightly adapted from the ones in the repo.

Also note that this function is very slow. Maybe someone knows how to improve it.